# want to remove time from oracle date but c sharp datetime won't let me

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, oracle11g

I have an object that stores an oracle date in C# as a datetime.

```
public DateTime AA_ACTION_DATE { get; set; }
```

when I run my query I get the dateformat as expected: 2013-07-04 8:58:04 AM

however i need to do a filter on the results and the filter is on the date only not the time.

```
 _oAuditTrail = _oAuditTrail.FindAll(Function(p1) p1.AA_ACTION_DATE = CDate(objFilterRecord))
```

this works on other date objects that are stored without the time stamp as it defaults to midnight.

trunc seems to be the way to go but , it works in toad/database level but C# seems to get it mangled
same record appears as: 0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM

tried `to_date` and `to_char` and the same record gets mangled:

`to_date(AA_ACTION_DATE,'dd/mm/yy')` returns 0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM
`to_char(AA_ACTION_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')` returns 0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM

going nuts here as it should be a simple solution

Comment: `DateTime` is exactly that – a type that holds a date _and a time_.

Comment: `_oAuditTrail = _oAuditTrail.FindAll(Function(p1) p1.AA_ACTION_DATE = CDate(objFilterRecord))` - This doesn't look like a C# statement. It looks more like a VB.Net statement.

Comment: yes the project has the classes in c-sharp and the 'presentation' in vb.net - i didnt make that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 _oAuditTrail = _oAuditTrail.FindAll(Function(p1) p1.AA_ACTION_DATE = CDate(objFilterRecord))
```

looks really suspect to me. `CDate()` is something from VB.Net, not C#.

Anyways, as mentioned in other answers, what you're looking for is the [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property from your `DateTime` instance, which, as per the documentation, will return

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

Notice that you cannot "remove" the Time portion of the DateTime object, because it's part of the data structure, just like you cannot "remove" any other property from any other class, you can just set it to a non-significant value (such as `null` in the case of reference types), or just ignore it in your code.

Therefore, `new DateTime(2013,11,27)` will return `11/27/2013 12:00:00 AM`, which is the default value for the time "part" of a `DateTime` object when not specified explicitly.

Also notice that if your `oAuditTrail` records have their DateTimes created in this way, they will all default to `12:00:00 AM`, as opposed to "not having a time", which is just not possible.

Which leads to the conclusion that your statement should be written (in proper C# rather than VB.Net and using LINQ) like this:

```
_oAuditTrail = _oAuditTrail.Where(x => x.AA_ACTION_DATE.Date == someDateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: yes the project has the classes in c-sharp and the 'presentation' in vb.net - i didnt make that clear

Comment: the answer was right there solution was to use the date portion and only include the substing to compare and it worked. thanks all       _oAuditTrail = _oAuditTrail.FindAll(Function(p1) p1.AA_ACTION_DATE.Date = CDate(objFilterRecord.Substring(0, 10)))

Comment: @user3042616 I strongly recommend **against** using strings for DateTime comparisons, because they are prone to errors. the `DateTime` object perfectly allows the comparison you're trying to achieve, without resorting to `string` based stuff. At best you should `CDate(...).Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DateTime.Date` to get a new `DateTime` that contains just the date part with the time truncated to midnight. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Note that that still returns `DateTime`

Comment: Yes, however the time will be truncated to midnight as the op would hope. I have updated the answer to be clearer.